# Laravel - get model attribute from another model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Class `ModelA` has relationship `belongsTo` to `ModelB`. Is there any way to access that attribute from `ModelA`? Something like:

```
$this->model_b->model_b_attribute;
```

Also, is there a way to chain model to attribute? If I have `belongsTo` relationship from `ModelB` to `ModelC` could I do this:

```
$this->model_b->model_b_attribute->model_c;
```

**Edit:**

My code:

`ModelA` would be:

```
class LeaseTenant extends Model {

    protected $appends = ['is_deposit_paid'];

    public function lease_request()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\LeaseRequest');
    }

    public function getIsDepositPaidAttribute()
    {
        return $this->email == $this->lease_request->security_deposit_entry->bank_account->user->email;    
    }
}
```

And `ModelB`:

```
class LeaseRequest extends Model {

    protected $appends = ['security_deposit_entry'];

    public function getSecurityDepositEntryAttribute()
    {
        return Rent
                 ::where('property_id', $this->property_id)
                 ->where('lease_request_id', $this->id)
                 ->where('type', 'security_deposit')
                 ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->first();
    }
}
```

I want to access `Rent` table from `LeaseTenant`.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: @DiegoCespedes I am not sure how this can help, but I have posted my code

Comment: @niksrb it is important because it helps to understand your actual problem.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to create attribute in `ModelA` to access column from `ModelC` over attribute from `ModelB`. And it is possible! Thanks agaub

Comment: In your `LeaseRequest` model, on the query inside your `getSecurityDepositEntryAttribute()` method I think that search by `property_id` is redundant given the fact that the `LeaseRequest` seems to belong to a unique `Property`. Now, the type used in the Rent is a static one, does this will apply for every `LeaseRequest`? If so, you could create a relationship directly between LeaseRequest and Rent instead of doing the query manually. But anyway, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: There are more different types, `security_deposit` is not the only one, I am just showing that one here for simplicity.
If I do as you suggest and create a relationship instead of attribute, would there be a way to filter records from `Rent` table by `type` while accessing it over relationship from `LeaseRequest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a relationship `belongsTo` between `ModelA` and `ModelB`:

```
# ModelA.php

public function modelB()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ModelA::class);
}
```

Then you could also access the relationship to get the `ModelA` instance, from which you can access the `ModelA` attributes.

```
$modelA = ModelA::find(1);
$name = $modelA->modelB->name;
//                      ^^^^^^ modelB attribute
```

Also, if you have another belongsTo relationship inside ModelB, you can do this:

```
$name = ModelA::find(1)->modelB->modelC->name;
//                                      ^^^^^^ modelC attribute
```